# How to use google.maps.getLatLng?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
          $('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    // This URL won't work on your localhost, so you need to change it
    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
    $.getJSON( 'demo.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.getLatLng(marker.town), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
            });
        });
    });
});
      }
    </script>
```

Why does the google.maps.getLatLng not work?

UPDATE:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(geocoder.getLatLng(marker.town)), 'bounds': true })
```

How do I find the latutide and longitude based on a town name? I have just tried the above without result.

Comment: I think you need to do some research and then, if you don't have an answer, ask a better question.  Your question currently is "how do I get the geographic coordinates of a "town" (I think).  That is a FAQ (how to get the geographic coordinates of an address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the google.maps.getLatLng not work?

Where do you find that in the documentation?

The correct syntax for the [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor is:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<latitude>, <longitude>)
```

where `<latitude>` and `<longitude>` are numbers

To get the geographic coordinates of a postal address, you need to use a [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

Comment: I want to get the latitude and longitude based on a town name.

Comment: That certainly wasn't clear from your question.  You need to use the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) for that.

Comment: I have tried `$('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', { 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    'position': new google.maps.LatLng(geocoder.getLatLng(marker.town)), 
    'bounds': true 
   })´

Comment: Put that in your question please.  Code posted in the comments is very difficult to read.  Also look at the documentation for the geocoder (the link is in both my answer and my previous comment), in v3 there is no "getLatLng" method, there are several examples available to help you understand how it works.